# yacc: e - line 85 of "tac.y", a token appears on the lhs of a production

Tags: yacc, lex

What is the exact meaning of the error:
yacc: e - line 85 of "tac.y", a token appears on the lhs of a production

line 85:

```
T:  INT { strcpy($$.type,"int"); }
            |
             REAL { strcpy($$.type,"real"); }
```

I have associated a attribute to T

```
%union{
  struct attribute{
    char name[20];
    char type[20];
  }attr;
}
%token <attr> ID
%token <attr> E
%token <attr> T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means what it says: that you are attempting to provide a derivation for a *token*. Tokens come from the lexcal analysis, so they cannot have grammatical rules associated with them.

I guess you meant to declare the (semantic value) *type* of `T`:

```
%type <attr> T
```

You probably need to change the declaration of `E` too.

Avoiding this kind of confusion is one of the reasons it is common to use ALL_CAPS for terminals (tokens) and `lower-case` for non-terminals.